# Swift Firebase Facebook Login - Gets Name, but email returns nil

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication

Recently my facebook login hasn't been working. It doesn't save into my database but in Firebase authentication it shows someone signed in with facebook but the email is blank. It doesn't save any data to my database which it should. The email is returning nil. My google sign in works. I've checked all the connections and they all seem to be fine. (I could have missed something) anyone have any suggestions on what connections I should check? Not sure what to do...

**More Info**

I printed my graph request... not sure if this helps to debug

```
let loginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: self.facebookPermissions, from: self, handler: { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                loginManager.logOut()
                let message: String = "An error has occured. \(String(describing: error))"
                let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok ", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
                // user cancelled login
                loginManager.logOut()
            } else {
                let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
                guard let accessTokenString = accessToken?.tokenString else { return }
                let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessTokenString)

                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
                    if (error != nil) {
                        // handle error
                        print(error ?? "Error")
                    } else {
                        let ref = Database.database().reference()

                        // guard for user id
                        guard let uid = user?.uid else {
                            return
                        }
                        let usersReference = ref.child("user_profiles").child(uid)

                        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"])
                        graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                            if error != nil {
                                // Process error
                                print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                            } else {
                                guard let data: [String:AnyObject] = result  as? [String:AnyObject] else {
                                    print("Can't pull data from JSON")
                                    return
                                }
                                guard let userName: String = data["name"] as? String else {
                                    print("Can't pull username from JSON")
                                    return
                                }
                                guard let userID: String = data["id"] as? String else {
                                    print("Can't pull ID from JSON")
                                    return
                                }
                                let imgURLString = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(userID)/picture?type=large" as String
                                guard let userEmail: String = data["email"] as? String else {
                                    print("Can't pull email from JSON")
                                    print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                                    return
                                }


                                // initial # posts = 0
                                let values = ["name": userName, "email": userEmail, "facebookID": userID, "profPicString": imgURLString] as [String : Any]

                                // update database with new user
                                usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                                    // error in database save
                                    if err != nil {
                                        print(err ?? "Error saving user to database")
                                        return
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        })
                        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                        // Present the main view
                        if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Customer Profile") {
                            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

[image]

Comment: so what´s in self.facebookPermissions?

Comment: let facebookPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

Comment: I've added a new google info plist and tried that, I've tried deleting the app from my facebook accounts...

Comment: And my google sign in works, so I am not sure what I could be doing wrong

Comment: So it gets my correct id, correct name, correct image but no email????

Comment: I've tried this with 2 facebook accounts I've had for a while and have worked before

Comment: you do know that having 2 fb accounts is not allowed, right? just saying.

Comment: anyway, if it worked before and now it doesn´t, i would file a bug

Comment: I need to release a update.... jeeeez filing a bug sounds like it would take forever to resolve

Comment: When I comment out the email everything works and everything saves.... :(

Comment: what happens for this FB user when you test via the Graph API explorer?  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Nice tool, the one account says the email is missing or hasn't been confirmed the other account it pulls all the info. The problem is now that in my app the facebook login is still linked to the old account, how do I remove it? I've logged into the facebook account and removed it from "apps" and I've deleted it off the facebook app yet it still brings up the bad account instead of the good one.

Comment: Fixed back email account linked account to facebook login by deleting facebook profile and then login resets to select which account/ sign in, then sign in with good account and can login in to bad account on facebook.com if you want too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **Swift 5** I found the email inside **providerData** which is an array of [FIRUserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Protocols/FIRUserInfo):

```
if AccessToken.current != nil {
    let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (res, err) in
        if err != nil || res == nil {
            //...
            return
        }
        guard let providerData = res?.user.providerData else {
            //...
            return
        }
        for firUserInfo in providerData {
            print(firUserInfo.providerID)
            print(firUserInfo.email ?? "Email not found")
        }
    }
}
```